# How to save a value to localstorage from a select menu as soon as u select the option? It is not working

Tags: javascript, select, google-chrome-extension, null, local-storage

I have the following, but I keep getting a return value of **`null`** instead of the value I was trying to store. Here is my code:

```
function mySelectValue() {
    // Add an event listener for the value
    document.getElementById('mySelectValue').addEventListener('change', function() {
      // Get the value of the name field.
      var mySelectValue = document.getElementById('mySelectValue').value;

      // Save the name in localStorage.
      localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', mySelectValue);
    });
}
```

However when I try to retrieve the value, it is **`null`** which I think means that the value was not stored.

Basically, as soon as I select the option (not submit it yet), I want it to be stored in localstorage. Also I want it to overwrite the value if I change my selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allowed to use jQuery, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySelectValue').change(function(){
         localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

You have problem somewhere else this code works you can check it here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zZHG6/)

Comment: hmm let me try it. yes I can use jquery I just need to add it to the page.

Comment: By the way your function (mySelectValue) should be checking if DOM is loaded before attaching the event

Comment: unfortunately, **`null`** is returned.

Comment: I wrapped your code in `$(function(){ });` to only run after dom is ready but still returns **`null`**. Your code does not work. What's wrong?

Comment: It works!! See my deviation to test for my exact purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/zZHG6/1/

Comment: This was fun :) Only one thing -- how do I get it to not say null (say something else) if nothing is defined in localstorage yet?

Comment: I figured it out: `if (localStorage.getItem("mySelectValue") === null) { document.write("whatever you want"); }`

Comment: I was just modifying your fiddle with this fix :-)